# disable option + delete/left_arrow/right_arrow key combos on remote linux ssh

Tags: ssh, macintosh

How do I disable option + delete/->/<- key combos when ssh into a remote linux box from my MacBook? Alternatively, map option + delete to the same function as command.+ delete. Currently I get [D, [C, etc on the screen, which is quite annoying. Thanks!

Comment: For the next down voter, could you suggest a better forum to ask this question? I will close it immediately and migrate over. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a comprehensive answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154292/iterm-going-one-word-backwards-and-forwards), in particular the natural text editing setting.

In summary:

> - Go to Preferences... > Profiles > Keys
> - Press Load Preset...
> - Select Natural Text Editing
>
> Then, you can move a word backwards using <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> +
>   <kbd>←</kbd> and a word forwards using <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> +
>   <kbd>→</kbd>. Also you can delete a word backwards using  <kbd>Option
>   ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌫</kbd>, delete the whole line using <kbd>Command
>   ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌫</kbd>, and more.